# HolyCoin how to add this coin to the the bitcoin markets

Tags: exchanges

I am the founder of HolyCoin and the HolyCoin Wallet and I need to know how do I get my HolyCoin on the Bitcoin markets so that the HolyCoin will begin to make money on the markets like Bitcoin have done and now Bitcoin is $577.1 on the markets.I want people to by Holycoins like they by Bitcoins. Thank you. Karen A. Atkins.

Comment: There's a market for gold, does this mean I can create a similar market for my used tissues? It doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 2):

This question exhibits perhaps a lack of understanding Bitcoin's value.

Bitcoin is valuable, because there are people that want to acquire it. It doesn't "make money", but asymmetric demand and supply change its price. Therefore, you need to create demand for your HolyCoin. As demand develops exchanges will discover it, and as exchanges discover it, it gains more exposure, and as it gains more exposure, it'll be more useful and demand will increase. – That is, if your coin has some sort of unique appeal to compete successfully among some [700 odd](http://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/views/all/) other cryptocurrencies of which at least 90% are essentially irrelevant.